# Compile multiple .c files with makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I would like to compile multiple .c files at once using a makefile.
I already made this:

```
CC= gcc

CPPFLAGS = -I.

CFLAGS = -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic

TARGET = test

RM = rm

OBJECTS = xxx.o yyy.o zzz.o

SOURCES = $(OBJECTS:.o =.c)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TAREGT)

clean:

         $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TAREGT) : $(OBJECTS)

         $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJECTS) : $(SOURCES) 

         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $^
```

I have no Idea why this does not work("nothing to be done for "all"). Someone has an idea?

Comment: looks like you have `TARGET` misspelled: `$(TAREGT)`

Comment: Ohh thanks. I fixed it now it says "gcc: fatal error: no input files
" somehow it cant find input files.

Comment: Take a look at your variables (e.g. `$(info $(SOURCES))`) before you try to use them; you've made at least one mistake there. And show us the command which Make is trying to execute-- it will be in the output of Make, just above the error.

Comment: @Beta, unfortunately we can guess the command is just going to be `gcc -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic -I. -c`

Answer (score 2):

This line is creating a circular dependency:

```
SOURCES = $(OBJECTS:.o =.c)
```

Try replacing it with this:

```
SOURCES = $(patsubst %.o,%.c,$(OBJECTS))
```

Comment: These two lines are absolutely equivalent. The first variant is just a shorthand. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html

Comment: @Alexey Semenyuk They should be equivalent, but they're not. The first creates a circular dependency error, and the second one does not. Try it! I have.

Comment: They are equivalent. The true problem with this expression is that extra whitespace between 'o' and '=' chars prevents it from working. It should be `SOURCES = $(OBJECTS:.o=.c)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `-o $@` in your 'sources to objects' rule. Thus it doesn't create anything.

You have also spelling error - your `$(TARGET)` is 'test', but your 'all' rule depends on `$(TAREGT)` which is empty. You are also using `$(TAREGT)` as input to compile 'test'.

You don't need to specify `$(SOURCES)` or "sources to objects" rule - implicit rules will do the trick.

In fact your "sources to objects" rule is incorrect - it says that each object depends on all sources. If you want each object to depend on one source you should use either suffix rule, pattern rule or static pattern rule. Or just implicit rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(OBJECTS) : $(SOURCES)
```

The above tells Make that every .o file depends on all sources, i.e. if you change one of your .c files Make will recompile all .o files. Not something what you really want, I guess. I'd rework this rule as follows:

```
$(foreach s,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(filter %$(basename $(notdir $s)).o,$(OBJECTS)): $s))
```

This will iterate every source in `SOURCES`, find corresponding .o file in `OBJECTS` and create correct rule: `<obj>: <source>`. It is that complicated to work in case of more complex mapping between source and object files. Say, when building object files in separate directory.

This cryptic code will work even for the following weird source to object file mapping:

```
SOURCES := a.cpp boo/b.c c.C
OBJECTS := foo/a.o bar/b.o c.o
$(foreach s,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(filter %$(basename $(notdir $s)).o,$(OBJECTS)): $s))
```

It will generate the following rules:

```
foo/a.o: a.cpp
bar/b.o: boo/b.c
c.o: c.C
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for you help, it is working now

I just added some rules:

```
CC= gcc
CPPFLAGS = -I.
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic
TARGET = test
RM = rm
SOURCES = xxx.c yyy.c zzz.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET)

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: You still don't have `-o $@` in the last rule. And it is still not needed since there is implicit rule which does the same.